# Issues in mapping master/details scenario via NHiberate, FluentNHibernate

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, entity-framework, fluent-nhibernate

I want to implement the following requirement:

**Edit**
What I need is. There can be one master location and detail locations (one-many). Each location can multiple cars. The master location has its own carname (on carname table), and cartext and IsCar(on CarText table). Detail location use carname from master location, but has its own columns on CarText table. Mutliple master locations are allowed (each master has many detail locations).

How should I design the Car class, and the ORM mapping in Fluent NHibernate??

Below is the C# classes:

```
Below is the tables:

    Table Location:
    LocationId

    Table CarName:
    CarId, LocationId, Name, Colour

The LocationId allows multiple cars. 

    Table CarText:
    CarTextId, CarId, LocationId, Text, IsCar
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't map a single class to two database tables, why not just have one table with fields from both tables?

Comment: take a look at the `<join />` mapping http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/04/20/nhibernate-mapping-lt-join-gt.aspx

Comment: @eulerfx I think two db tables are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Edited: is this class structure nearer to your requirement?

```
public class Location
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Car MasterCar { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IDictionary<Location, string> TextsByLocation { get; set; }
}
```

Edit2: this better?

```
public class MasterLocation
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Location> Details { get; set; }
    public virtual string CarName { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public virtual MasterLocation Master { get; set; }
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Cars> Cars { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name
    {
        get { return Location.Master.CarName; }
        set { Location.Master.CarName = value; }
    }
    public virtual string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your advice. In answering your question, the LocationId in carname table allows multiple master cars. Please see my update on the table secion. What I need is each location has a master car, each master car has multiple child car. A master car has both 
All cars share the same car name on carname table, each Car has its own text field on cartext table. For example, a master car has all fields on both tables. Thus, master car can perform CRUD operation on both table. Whereas, children of the master car can only has CRUD operations on car text (and locationid) on the CarText table.

Comment: I have to correct my requirement. Could you please refer to my update. Thanks!